# Why is onConnectionFailed() not called during Android Google+ authentication?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

Below is my implementation of the boilerplate for G+ authentication. A subclass calls resolveSignInErrors() when a button is pressed, however the implementation fails to work. The issue is that when resolveSignInErrors() is called mConnectionResult is null so nothing happens.

I would expect mConnectionResult to be set in onConnectionFailed() but that is not being called, despite a call being made to GoogleApiClient.connect(). Why would onConnectionFailed() not be called?

I find this API utterly confusing.

```
public class GooglePlusActivity extends MyActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    boolean mIntentInProgress = false;
    final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    protected boolean mSignInClicked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initialiseGoogleApiClient();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }

    protected void initialiseGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            mConnectionResult = connectionResult;
            if (mSignInClicked) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void resolveSignInError() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "resolveSignInError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mConnectionResult!=null && mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "inside if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this, "inside try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                getGoogleApiClient().connect();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!getGoogleApiClient().isConnecting()) {
                getGoogleApiClient().connect();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I see no reason why it couldnt get call with the code given, are you sure its not something with mIntentInProgress no set right?

Comment: Or is it just connecting properly?  After you approve the app once, subsequent calls should succeed until the user de-authorizes the app.